# Test Case issue on Android

Tags: android, service, junit

I have Class A extending IntentService and Processing some work.

```
Class A extend IntentService {

    onHandleIntent(Intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            Messenger messenger = (Messenger) extras.get(NetworkConstant.MESSENGER_KEY);
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            try {
                messenger.send(msg);
            }
                    catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Now i have another Class B

```
Class B {
  private void startNetworkService(Listener l) {
        Messenger messenger = new Messenger(handler);
        Intent networkServiceIntent = new Intent(context, A.class);
        context.startService(networkServiceIntent);
    }

/** The handler. */
    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
           Listener.onSuccess();
       }

}
```

Now i am creating testCase Calling startNetworkService() method  and i have passed Listener receiving  call back on Sucess.

```
Class Test extend AndroidTestCase implement Listener{
   testService(){
      B b = new b();
      b.startNetworkService(this);
    }
  onSucess(){
    never got call back here.
  }
}
```

**Problem :-  I never got call back on Success method.**  if i use

```
mSem = new Semaphore(0); 
mSem.acquire();
```

to put wait on Test. It got Stuck and Test case not going forward. Can you please help me how to test class that calling other class using service

Comment: you did not pass an intent extra so it does not go into the if condition

Answer (score 0):

Use `mContext = getContext();`

```
Class Test extend AndroidTestCase implement Listener{   

 private static Context mContext = null;

public void setUP() throws Exception{
    super.setUp();

}

public void tearDown() throws Exception{
    super.tearDown();
}


private void precondition() {

    mContext = getContext();

    assertNotNull(mContext);
    }

  testService(){
   precondition();
   // ....
}
```

Comment: Hi I am already passing getContext() in Class B forget to tell. Everything working fine service got Started . after completing response come back to  private Handler handler = new Handler()  in Class B . but after that it disappear. i have put breakpoint also  and it disappear also

Answer (score 0):

I got Issue Problem is in  messenger.send(msg); in Class A.

```
 Messenger messenger = (Messenger) extras.get(NetworkConstant.MESSENGER_KEY);
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            try {
                messenger.send(msg);
            }
                    catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Where Messenger is passed by Class B .
After  messenger.send(msg)   call back never return to Class B handler

```
  private Handler handler = new Handler() {
           Listener.onSuccess();
       }
```